# Magento 2.3.3 Getting issue in custom module GraphQL

Tags: magento2.3.3, webapi, pwa, graphql

I would like to create custom **GraphQL** for a custom module. but I am facing an issue. see below **GraphQL response**.
[image: graphql-response]

In the above image, you can see I am able to get the response of `days` and `**details**` value but unable to get the value of `dates` it will return always null but actually value is present.

Below is my `schema.graphql`

```
type Query {
    getInformation(id: String!): StoreHolidayInfo @resolver (class: "\\Namespace\\Modulename\\Model\\Resolver\\StoreHolidayInfo") @doc(description:"Returns holiday information about store")
}
type StoreHolidayInfo {
   dates: [holidayDates]
   days: String
   details: [holidayDetails]
}
type holidayDates {
   repetitive: Int
   normal: Int
   shipping_off_day: Int
}

type holidayDetails {
   holiday_id: Int
   holiday_name: String
   holiday_applied_stores: String
   holiday_date_from: String
   holiday_date_to: String
   holiday_comment: String
   is_repetitive: Int
   is_active: Int
   all_store: Int
}
```

Below is my Resolver class.

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Namespace\Modulename\Model\Resolver;

use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlInputException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\Resolver\Argument\SearchCriteria\Builder as SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;
use Namespace\Modulename\Api\StoreInformationManagementInterface;

/**
 * Class StoreHolidayInfo
 * @package Namespace\Modulename\Model\Resolver
 */
class StoreHolidayInfo implements ResolverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var StoreInformationManagementInterface
     */
    protected $storeInformationManagement;

    /**
     * StoreHolidayInfo constructor.
     * @param StoreInformationManagementInterface $storeInformationManagement
     */
    public function __construct(
        StoreInformationManagementInterface $storeInformationManagement
    ) {
        $this->storeInformationManagement = $storeInformationManagement;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function resolve(Field $field, $context, ResolveInfo $info, array $value = null, array $args = null)
    {
        if (!isset($args['id']) || empty($args['id'])) {
            throw new GraphQlInputException(__('"id" argument should be specified and not empty'));
        }

        $storeHoliday = $this->storeInformationManagement->getStoreHolidayInformation($args['storelocator_id']);

        return [
            'dates' => $storeHoliday[0]['dates'],
            'days' => $storeHoliday[0]['days'],
            'details' => $storeHoliday[0]['details']
        ];
    }
}
```

If I print the `$storeHoliday` object in Resolver file I am getting the below response.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [dates] => Array
                (
                    [repetitive] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1-14
                            [1] => 1-15
                            [2] => 1-14
                            [3] => 1-15
                            [4] => 1-26
                        )

                    [normal] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 01-14-2020
                            [1] => 01-15-2020
                            [2] => 01-26-2020
                        )

                    [shipping_off_day] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [days] => 1
            [details] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [holiday_id] => 1
                            [holiday_name] => Kites festival
                            [holiday_applied_stores] => 2,3,4
                            [holiday_date_from] => 2020-01-14
                            [holiday_date_to] => 2020-01-15
                            [holiday_comment] => <p>Kites festival</p>
                            [is_repetitive] => 1
                            [is_active] => 1
                            [all_store] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [holiday_id] => 2
                            [holiday_name] => Republic day
                            [holiday_applied_stores] => 2,3,4
                            [holiday_date_from] => 2020-01-26
                            [holiday_date_to] => 2020-01-26
                            [holiday_comment] => <p>Republic day</p>
                            [is_repetitive] => 1
                            [is_active] => 1
                            [all_store] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

So, in short, I am unable to get the value of `dates`. what's going wrong in the above code. can anybody help me to solve this issue?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: do you get any idea about this issue...

Comment: Still not getting any idea.

Comment: 'dates' => $storeHoliday[0]['dates']  ----

here are you  getting data...?

Comment: Yes, I can get data, you can see array in my question.

Comment: in query you set    repetitive: Int

as int but your returning
a  array to that...

Comment: plz pass   single interger value to ----     repetitive: Int   --   to this data type 

and check with that..

Comment: What can I set instead of `Int`?

Comment: I know set a single value to `repetitive` but in my case, I need to send array. If I pass a single value then how can I pass other values?

Comment: [holidayDates]   --  set a type like this... within  --[ ]

Comment: is that repetitive  array is fully dynamic  ho...

Comment: Don't get your point, can you share pice of code so I can better understand.

Comment: that idea is working or not ...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with below code.

```
type StoreHolidayInfo {
    dates: holidayDates,
    days: String,
    details: [holidayDetails]
}

type holidayDates {
    repetitive: [String] @doc(description: "holiday id"),
    normal: [String] @doc(description: "holiday id"),
    shipping_off_day: [String] @doc(description: "holiday id")
}

type holidayDetails {
    holiday_id: Int @doc(description: "holiday id"),
    holiday_name: String @doc(description: "holiday name"),
    holiday_applied_stores: String @doc(description: "holiday applied stores"),
    holiday_date_from: String @doc(description: "holiday date from"),
    holiday_date_to: String @doc(description: "holiday date to"),
    holiday_comment: String @doc(description: "holiday comment"),
    is_repetitive: Int @doc(description: "yearly repitive"),
    is_active: Int @doc(description: "is active holiday"),
    all_store: Int @doc(description: "all store"),
}
```

And add change below code in resolver.

```
return [
        'dates' => array(
            'repetitive' => $storeHoliday[0]['dates']['repetitive'],
            'normal' => $storeHoliday[0]['dates']['normal'],
            'shipping_off_day' => $storeHoliday[0]['dates']['shipping_off_day']
        ),
        'days' => $storeHoliday[0]['days'],
        'details' => $storeHoliday[0]['details']
    ];
```

It should work then.

Comment: It working like charm! You are a genius..... Actually I have defined  `dates: holidayDates`  is an array. after remove define `holidayDates` as a simple string it's working.

Answer (score 2):

i'm not sure 
but just try out

you will get idea

```
type StoreHolidayInfo {
   dates: [holidayDates]
   days: String
   details: [holidayDetails]
}


type holidayDates {
   repetitive: [repetitive_list]  
   normal: Int
   shipping_off_day: Int
}

type repetitive_list{
repetitive_list:int
}
```

> i just gave for one element
>
> just try then change to all
>
> and also you need just change in your
>
> array print [repetitive][repetitive_list]

```
[dates] => Array
                (
                    [repetitive] => Array
                        (
       [repetitive_list]=>Array(

                            [0] => 1-14
                            [1] => 1-15
                            [2] => 1-14
                            [3] => 1-15
                            [4] => 1-26
                        )
    )

                    [normal] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 01-14-2020
                            [1] => 01-15-2020
                            [2] => 01-26-2020
                        )

                    [shipping_off_day] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )
```

Comment: Thanks for your time but What is the difference between `[repetitive]` and `[repetitive_list]` at the end, both are a return array and you define `repetitive_list: int` = Int but it's value return array.

Comment: you already defined correct query but again  you need an extra array to print array value's on array     ---  not an Int value ...

Comment: between [repetitive] and [repetitive_list]  -----   both are printing an array


with array of array

Comment: The issue is in the same position. I would like to know what type are define for an index array return? If an array is associative so you can assign Int, String,Float etc.. to key like `type holidayDetails {}`

Comment: still not yet solved ah..

Comment: No still not resolved. Just need to find `In case of the return index array what type we define in **schema.graphql** Int, String, Float, etc...?

Comment: just define extra field with ID

that's it

Comment: type repetitive_list{
repetitive_list:int
-
index:ID
}